Endless loading of the inspector window with HDRP shaders
I have a project with HDRP installed in it. After I converted the standard unity materials into HDRP shaders, if I selected any object on the scene, then I started an endless loading of the inspector, which reached up to 25 hours or more.
I tried different things, deleted the library folder, reinstalled HDRP, changed unity versions. But none of this helped me.
